# Android LinearLayout, last added children stealing click for onClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

**Setup:**

I have a custom LinearLayout that has a TextView and an ImageView inside it (my attempts to resolve the issue are commented out):

```
public class MyTextView extends LinearLayout {

    private final TextView textView;
    private final ImageView imageView;

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);

        textView = new TextView(context);
        imageView = new ImageView(context);

        LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);

        /* imageView.setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true);
         textView.setDuplicateParentStateEnabled(true); */

        /* imageView.setFocusable(false);
        textView.setFocusable(false);
        textView.setTextIsSelectable(false); */

        addView(textView);
        addView(imageView);

        /* this.setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        this.setClickable(true); */

    }
}
```

I'm including this custom LinearLayout in a larger layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <my.package.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm setting an onClickListener this way:

```
final MyTextView textView = (MyTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Code
    }
});
```

**My issue:**

The onClickListener only fires if I tap the ImageView, and not the TextView. I'd like it to work if I tap any part of the LinearLayout instead.

I can't understand why this wouldn't work, not even with e.g. setDescendantFocusability set to FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS, and would appreciate an explanation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that [`setMovementMethod`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setMovementMethod%28android.text.method.MovementMethod%29) was being called on the TextView and I didn't notice.